# How to create a file in webroot during runtime in java web project?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, jboss

Hi i must create a XML file in the project using java dynamically and must read it using the base Path URL. i can read the File when i create it manually, but not able to create it dynamically. When i use **File f1 = new File("test.XML");** it create the file in the **tomcat's Bin folder**. The file must be created in the Project while Running in both Tomcat and Jboss EAP 6.

Comment: Why don't you just provide the absolute path as a config variable?

Comment: f1.getAbsolutePath(); directs to the tomcat's Bin folder.

Comment: Use `<context-param>` to give values to web.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the real path of the web application using the servlet context:

```
new File( servletContext.getRealPath( "/text.XML" ) );
```

Note: if you're running tomcat/jboss on Linux, you'll probably have to give permission to write in the webapp folder though, which is most likely forbidden by default.

Quoting from Servlet API docs of [`ServletContext.getRealPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns a String containing the real path for a given virtual path.
>   For example, the path "/index.html" returns the absolute file path on
>   the server's filesystem would be served by a request for
>   "http://host/contextPath/index.html", where contextPath is the context
>   path of this ServletContext..